# How can I detect if a file has been modified using lastModified()

Tags: java

I know I can use lastModified() to get the last modified time of a file. What I don't understand is that how can I use this method to detect if a file has been changed or not. Do I compare it with the current time?
I was trying to do the following but I don't think it works

```
long time = xx.lastModified();
if(time != localtime)
//.....
```

Comment: You'd need to have a cache of the last modified time. Then when you query it again you'd compare the new value with the cached value.

Comment: What @Slaw says is right, but the last modified time can be effected without actually changing the file content - for example, by using the `touch` command on a *nix system.  To really know if the file has changed, you'd need to store a hash of the files (md5sum, sha256, etc) and for the comparison re-hash and compare the values of the 2 hashes.

Comment: @user10973291, what do you mean by changed? Changed since given file was created? Or changes since last time you checked it or last time you know it was changed?

Comment: @ivanivan  Having a new filestamp may on its own qualify as "being changed".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen depends on how specific you want to get.  If the md5sum/sha256sum/whatever hash of a file hasn't changed, then you know it is the real deal.  AFAIK the time stamp, etc. is a file system meta-data thing, not related to the actual file and its contents.

Comment: @ivanivan Exactly.  In other places it might be a dummy file where the timestamp is important in its meaning.  Not knowing this makes it hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

for this problem there are so many solutions, i know this one:
For a single file, a thread is launched to check the lastModified value and compare it with the previous value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public abstract class FileWatcher extends TimerTask {
  private long timeStamp;
  private File file;

  public FileWatcher( File file ) {
  this.file = file;
  this.timeStamp = file.lastModified();
}

public final void run() {
  long timeStamp = file.lastModified();

  if( this.timeStamp != timeStamp ) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    onChange(file);
  }
}

protected abstract void onChange( File file );
}
```

here is the main for the test:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileWatcherTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // monitor a single file
  TimerTask task = new FileWatcher( new File("c:/temp/text.txt") ) {
    protected void onChange( File file ) {
      // here we code the action on a change
      System.out.println( "File "+ file.getName() +" have change !" );
    }
  };

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  // repeat the check every second
  timer.schedule( task , new Date(), 1000 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to know if some file was modified than you certanly don't have to retrieve last modification time. Java NIO has `inotify` (on Linux) wrapper called `WatchService` 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html .

You can register `ENTRY_MODIFY` event on your file of interest and then wait till the associated watch key to be signalled.

Note that in Linux we have more granular event kinds than Java NIO provides us with. For instance `ENTRY_MODIFY` will be triggered when either writing or changing attributes occurred. `intofiy` by constast has separated type of events for that: `IN_ATTRIB` and `IN_WRITE`.